# How do I select this element in JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

This is the HTML structure:

[image]

```
Element link = doc.select("div.subtabs p").first();
```

That does not seem to work. How do I select that `p`?

Comment: +1 - Very clear question

Comment: As the old saying goes "A screen shot of an HTML page's source with a overlaid scribbly bit pointing out which element you want to select paints a thousand words"

Comment: @Rob The original saying is in Latin, IIRC.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The DIV with the class="subtabs" is not in fact the parent of the `p` element but instead is the sibling of `p`. To retrieve the `p`, you'll need to first get a reference to the parent DIV that has the id="content":

```
Element link = doc.select("div#content > p").first();
```

Additionally, you'll need the `>` symbol to indicate that you're selecting a child of div#content.

> parent > child: child elements that descend directly from parent, e.g. div.content > p finds p elements; and body > * finds the direct children of the body tag

If you get stuck with a JSOUP CSS selector in the future, check out the [JSOUP Selector Syntax cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), which has some nice examples and explanations.

Comment: Thanks, if there were another <p> tag in let's say the form tag, will this query  go to that <p> tag ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure, but it should be really easy to just add one in real quick and see what happens. I suspect that the `.first()` may ensure you only grab the first instance of the `p`, but trying it is the best way to determine for sure :) One thing to watch for is that, if you select a collection, you'll need `Elements` with an "s" instead of just `Element`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Judging by the context here in this example, and by the fact that we know `Element` is a single entity and not a collection, my money is on just 1 p being returned. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax.  If your `p` wasn't the first one (or only one), you'd have to take a different approach.

Comment: Okay, then I iterate through elements

Comment: Exactly.  Or `:eq(n) elements whose sibling index is equal to n`. Check out that link, the Cookbook link. Jsoup is a really great tool, and if you use jQuery a lot, it really helps make it a smooth transition. Good luck! :)

Comment: "#content > p" will match all p that are direct children of #content, but not grandchildren, grandgrandchildren etc, so only 1-st level descendants AKA children. That's how > makes it different from "#content p", which would match all p descendant of #content.

Answer (score 4):

`div#content p`. It is not a child of `.subtabs`.

Comment: +1 - It is in fact also correct to omit the `>` in this situation:  `E F --> an F element descended from an E element`.

Comment: The best selector depends highly on the rest of the HTML structure and how stable it is. My suggestion only solves the acute problem. From what we see in the screenshot it is probably better to assume `p`s inside `.subtabs` and use the `>`.

Comment: and I think that's fine. We're not here to solve all the op's problems but IMHO just provide enough to a) help him/her understand at least one possible solution that solves the immediate problem, and b) hopefully provide enough guidance so that if said answer doesn't completely solve the problem, he/she can easily figure it out on his/her own. If you really *really* wanted to be thorough, you could add what you told me as an additional point in your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The **p** tag you are trying to extract is not a child of the **div**. It is a sibling. The parent div's id is **content** and the **p** tag you want is the first **p** tag within its parent. So use `doc.select("div#content > p").first();`

The **#** means id and **>** means RHS is a child to LHS. So the statement means get first paragraph which is child to div with id as **content**

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb) is very helpful in constructing CSS selectors for jSoup, simply by point and click. It has saved me hours of development time when trying to target specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

`Element link = doc.select("div.subtabs + p")` 
It finds element immediately preceded by sibling

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Element link = doc.select("div.subtabs > p").first();
```